# Testing if the correct select option is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a dropdown list that has a list of locations.
When someone views the page, I want to test to to see if the default selected value is "anywhere"

```
RSpec.describe AccountController, type: :controller do
  context "with render_views" do
    render_views

    describe "GET new" end
      it "defaults to anywhere in location drop down list" do
         get :new
         expect(....) ???
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can write feature tests for view testing, which is much and and more specific.

Comment: @ArupRakshit what do you mean?  I am doing a feature test, but I guess it is more integration you mean?

Comment: yes integration test is what I meant. [link](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec)

Comment: but can I do it doing controller testing? not sure when to do a controller test and feature test.

Comment: I never did that thing in controller, you may try the answer given below. I am not confident in your case in controller spec.

Comment: have you tried `expect(page).to have_select(dropdown, :selected => selected_text)`

Answer (score 0):

You can test in the HTML if the `<option>` with the expected value has the attribute `selected`.

As [shown in this example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp), here's how a selected option looks like:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

You can use [`assert_select`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select) (even if you use RSpec) to test the expected HTML tag.